# Xamarin Maps Shows Gray Tiles

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm new to xamarin and working on basics to get the hang of it.

been following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map

as can be seen below it looks like I'm able to request but I still have gray tiles. what could cause this? is something wrong with my api key?
[image]

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    private StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
    private Map map;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        map = new Map(
        MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                new Position(35.184657, 33.353528), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)))
        {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            WidthRequest = 960,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };



        stackLayout.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        stackLayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

        stackLayout.Children.Add(map);

        Content = stackLayout;
    }
```

**Debug Output**

```
04-17 09:36:29.242 E/GoogleCertificates( 3601): Failed to load 

com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates
04-17 09:36:29.242 E/GoogleCertificates( 3601): qq: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
04-17 09:36:29.242 E/GoogleCertificates( 3601):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:11)
04-17 09:36:29.242 E/GoogleCertificates( 3601):     at in.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:12)
04-17 09:36:29.242 E/GoogleCertificates( 3601):     at in.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:31)
04-17 09:36:29.242 E/GoogleCertificates( 3601):     at in.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:30)
04-17 09:36:29.242 E/GoogleCertificates( 3601):     at iy.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:35)
04-17 09:36:29.242 E/GoogleCertificates( 3601):     at iy.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:20)
04-17 09:36:29.242 E/GoogleCertificates( 3601):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ev.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:143)
04-17 09:36:29.242 E/GoogleCertificates( 3601):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fb.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:28)
04-17 09:36:29.242 E/GoogleCertificates( 3601):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
04-17 09:36:29.242 E/GoogleCertificates( 3601):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
04-17 09:36:29.242 E/GoogleCertificates( 3601):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think that if your API key is bad you will have problems navigating to the map page. I ran into this a week or two ago. Look at the application output and you should see a message about "contacting google map server"

Comment: What does it mean api key is bad? Shall I recreate it?

Comment: Can you see output for messages from the Google Maps component?

Comment: yes, I have updated the question accordingly. it says Failed to load com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates

Comment: If you see the Google logo but no tiles for the map it is often an indicator that something went wrong with the authorization at the Google Maps API.

Your output also says so too:

01-05 08:50:33.741 E/Google Maps Android API( 8860): Authorization failure. Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.

Comment: To over come this delete the app, rebuild with the correct key and re-deploy. It should now work as expected.

Comment: Deleted the debug folder run the project again and just worked fine :) thanks for the help